# Extjs date field popup calendar upward in iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, extjs, datepicker, sencha-architect

In ExtJS grid date field in iPad misbehaves as when we click on it the ipad keypad comes up hiding the calendar. If we hide the keypad calendar also goes. So unable to pick the date. Is there a remedy for this.? I thought of popup the calendar upward so that the keypad does not hide it. Is there a way to do that.

Thanks,

Anish Karunakaran.

Comment: What version of extjs?

Comment: Extjs 5.0.1 is the version

Comment: If already at 5, I'd recommend going to 5.1.0 and putting the question up over on the sencha forums. It could be a bug. I looked at release notes and there have been issues with ipads.